# How is iBooks rendering the index view so quickly when viewing a PDF? Or: how do draw UIImages on UIScrollView directly without UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, xamarin.ios, core-graphics

I have a 140 pages test PDF (the full Adobe PDF specification, http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf) and open it in iBooks. Then switch to index (thumbnail) view. If I scroll to the end fast enough I can see that I can scroll faster than iBooks renders the pages but it catches up pretty quickly on iPad 2.
I learn two things from this:

- First iBooks is showing 140 empty squares in the right size and then populates the preview.
- iBooks really renders all of the previews and keeps them in memory (if I scroll around I cannot spot any re-rendering)
- I also tested with another Adobe Spec that has 700+ pages: exactly same behavior! Fascinating!

The question is how are they doing it? I wrote some code that gets each page of the PDF as an image, adds it to a UIImageView and adds that to the scrollview.

I use the same technique and layout as iBooks does. It renders just as quick as iBooks but memory consumption is insane and especially when scrolling the app gets totally stuck after a while. Can anybody point me in the right direction? I already removed the PDF rendering for testing and it is really fast, so I can pin it down to the thumbnail generation.

**EDIT:**
If from the code below the PDF generation is removed and an empty `UIImageView` is returned instead, the performance is still extremely weak. So my assumption is that the UIImageView is causing the problem. How can I draw the PDF thumbs onto my `UIScrollView` without the requirement of 140 `UIImageViews`?

For those firm in Monotouch, here's the code I'm using to render the thumbs, maybe it shows an obvious weakness:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Gets the low res page preview of a PDF page. Does a quick image render of the page.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="iPage">the number of the page to render</param>
        /// <param name="oTergetRect">the target rect to fit the PDF page into</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The low res page image view.
        /// </returns>
        public static UIImageView GetLowResPagePreview (CGPDFPage oPdfPage, RectangleF oTargetRect)
        {
            RectangleF oOriginalPdfPageRect = oPdfPage.GetBoxRect (CGPDFBox.Media);
            RectangleF oPdfPageRect = PdfViewerHelpers.RotateRectangle( oPdfPage.GetBoxRect (CGPDFBox.Media), oPdfPage.RotationAngle);
            // If preview is requested for the PDF index view, render a smaller version.
            if (!oTargetRect.IsEmpty)
            {
                // Resize the PDF page so that it fits the target rectangle.
                oPdfPageRect = new RectangleF (new PointF (0, 0), GetFittingBox (oTargetRect.Size, oPdfPageRect.Size));
            }

            // Create a low res image representation of the PDF page to display before the TiledPDFView
            // renders its content.
            int iWidth = Convert.ToInt32 ( oPdfPageRect.Size.Width );
            int iHeight = Convert.ToInt32 ( oPdfPageRect.Size.Height );
            CGColorSpace oColorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();
            CGBitmapContext oContext = new CGBitmapContext(null, iWidth, iHeight, 8, iWidth * 4, oColorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast);

            // First fill the background with white.
            oContext.SetFillColor (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            oContext.FillRect (oOriginalPdfPageRect);
            // Scale the context so that the PDF page is rendered 
            // at the correct size for the zoom level.
            oContext.ConcatCTM ( oPdfPage.GetDrawingTransform ( CGPDFBox.Media, oPdfPageRect, 0, true ) );
            oContext.DrawPDFPage (oPdfPage);
            CGImage oImage = oContext.ToImage();
            UIImage oBackgroundImage = UIImage.FromImage( oImage );
            oContext.Dispose();
            oImage.Dispose ();
            oColorSpace.Dispose ();

            UIImageView oBackgroundImageView = new UIImageView (oBackgroundImage);
            oBackgroundImageView.Frame = new RectangleF (new PointF (0, 0), oPdfPageRect.Size);
            oBackgroundImageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
            oBackgroundImageView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
            oBackgroundImageView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.None;
            return oBackgroundImageView;
        }

        internal static RectangleF RotateRectangle ( RectangleF oRect, int iRotationAngle )
        {
            if ( iRotationAngle == 90 || iRotationAngle == 270 )
            {
                return new RectangleF (oRect.X, oRect.Y, oRect.Height, oRect.Width);
            }
            return oRect;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using 140 UIImageViews !!! use only just enough to fill the area and then recycle the ones that are no longer displayed.

How did Apple implement UITableView ?? Do you think they keep all tableview cells in memory??

Look at the PhotoScroller sample code and the corresponding WWDC 2010 video. I think it is named "Desigining apps with scrollViews"

WWDC 2011 video of similar name is continuation of the same trick of view reuse.

Hope this helps.

Comment: PhotoScroller is paged. That's easy. And StreetScroller will not suffer from lags by loading new data like it will happen for PDF thumbs.

Comment: Efficiently generating PDF thumbnails is a completely different problem. Even if you were given 140 pre generated images it won't solve your problem. 

subView recycling is possible even for non-paged UIScrollViews

Comment: I found a working example of a pretty good PDF reader here: https://github.com/vfr/Reader
It is using exactly the technique you describe. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the size of each `UIImageView`? Perhaps each of your thumbnails is actually the size of a full page.

Perhaps iBooks doesn't put each thumbnail in a `UIImageView`? Maybe the app is using something from CoreAnimation or even OpenGL ES?

Comment: You might have a point there. I removed the PDF page rendering and returned 140 empty UIImageViews instead and the performance is just as weak! So the PDF is not really the cause it seems. How can I make it happen without UIImageView?

Comment: The size of one UIImageView is 200x280, so that's not the cause.

Comment: I'm most familiar with OpenGL ES. You could do it this way but there's probably a better solution. Read about Core Animation and/or Core Graphics. You can probably get a nice performance increase with these technologies w/o the tediousness of OpenGL.